# Calling a stored procedure returning multiple table results inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to call a stored procedure (sp1) within another stored procedure (sp2), which is returning multiple table results?

I have to use the returned results in the executed stored procedure (sp2).

As far as I know this is not possible. But I want to make sure.

Is there any alternative to achieve this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `INSERT INTO <table> EXEC <sp>` for *one* result set.

But that won't work for multiple result sets.

And you can't nest it.  *(SP2 can use it when calling SP1.  But SP3 can't do the same thing if it calls SP2.)*

If you honestly have multiple result sets to return, you need to insert the results into tables.  Then the outer SP can just use those tables.

If the outer SP creates a temp table (`CREATE TABLE #temp`) then the inner SP can see it an insert into it.

Equally you could use a permanent table.  I'd recommend having a column called SPID and use @@spid as the value you insert into it.  *(@@spid identifys each session uniquely.)*  But then you have to remember to clean up after you've inserted into the table.

All of these option assume you can modify both SPs.  If you can't, I'm not sure that you can do this inside SQL Server.

Comment: "But that won't work for multiple result sets.": Actually it *will* work for multiple result sets, but only if they have compatible column definitions (i.e., if they could be UNIONed together, they effectively will be).

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a temp table inside the SP2 and use it in the SP1

Comment: Are you sure?  I thought if it was created in SP2 *(the inner SP)* then it's scope is limitted to the duration of SP2.  This would mean that it no longer exists by the time execution returns to SP1 *(the outer SP)*.  So, the temp table would need creating in SP1?

Comment: You can create a temp table, but no whit #TempTable, create it normally TempTable and after you use it you drop it

Comment: Then it's not a temp table.  `@table` = Table Variable.  `#table` = Temp Table.  `table` = Table.  If you mean a table, that you'll drop after it's use, don't call it a a temp table, that means something else.  Also, doing this has a major problem: If two separate sessions execute the same SP, the table cant be created twice.

Comment: And if you change the SP2 to a function that returns a table.

Comment: The OP's example returns 3 result sets.  You can't make a Table Valued Function that returns 3 result sets.